# Waiting for lock on /home/cloudera/.sbt/boot/sbt.boot.lock to be available

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to run a spark application using sbt. There is a detailed guide to set up a simple spark project using sbt [here](http://www.nodalpoint.com/development-and-deployment-of-spark-applications-with-scala-eclipse-and-sbt-part-1-installation-configuration/) and I am following it as is

After creating a spark program and adding the dependencies, when I try to create the `sbt package` I get the below message and nothing happens from there.

```
[cloudera@quickstart SampleApp]$ sbt package
Waiting for lock on /home/cloudera/.sbt/boot/sbt.boot.lock to be available...
```

I have my spark application running in quick start VM with version CDH 5.7.0.
I am not sure where am I going wrong. I have searched for the related issue but they are not for spark. Can anyone provide some light on this issue please?

Comment: Check that you have not run sbt for this project in another terminal or ide.

Comment: It started to run after 20 min when I was out for lunch. Later I discovered that it was a problem with my Internet which was very slow. So the steps I have followed are correct and I would recommend the link to every one who are new to spark.

Comment: In my country, I have the same problem with getting sbt dependencies and I need to use proxy. 
Use `sbt -v` to verbose what sbt is doing.

Comment: Do you have any process which uses ivy2 repository ?

Answer (score 0):

Run as root user.Cloud era user does not have access to sbt.Or change the permission